# Jump to next line containing text (vim)

Tags: vim

Is there a motion in vim that moves to the next line (up or down) that contains text? If I know the number of lines between it's easy to do something like `2j` to jump over a line, but if I want to repeat a macro on every line containing text it would be more widely applicable if I could generically jump to the next line with text on it.

Example:

```
this is a line
this is another line <-- cursor is at start of this line


line after a blank line <-- want motion that jumps to this line (blank line count unknown)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a command `:global`. It is not really a motion, but the whole loop packed into a single command:

```
:g/regex/command
```

BTW. If "command" is not given then "print" is assumed, so we have `:g/re/p` which is the true origin of the "grep" word/utility.

But if all you need is to move the cursor to the next line containing some "text" then it suffices to type simply

```
/text
```

Comment: Ahh.. not quite what I was hoping for but thanks for sharing that info about the global command because it gets me most of what I need for this scenario. I can use it to pick which lines I want to apply the macro to like `:g/\w$/norm! @q`

Comment: @JoshL Regex also works as "line number" in the command-line: `:/^$/print` will print the next non-empty line as well as moving the cursor to it. Or `:/begin/,/end/delete` will delete the lines between one containing "begin" and "end". Etc.

Answer (score 4):

To jump to the next non-empty line, you can perform this search:

```
/^.
```

(Press <kbd>/</kbd> then `^.` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Then press <kbd>n</kbd> each time you want to go to the next non-empty line.

This solution is only useful if not all the lines are elligible for the macro; otherwise, @Matt's solution is much better.

Answer (score 1):

`2}{j` seems to do what you ask for, assuming you start from a line that contains text.  "Paragraphs" are marked by a line with no text.

`2}` jumps forward two paragraphs.  `{` jumps to the blank line before the start of the target paragraph, and `j` moves down one line, putting you on the first character in the target paragraph.  Testing this, I see that lines containing only tabs and/or spaces are found.